# SSL client program getting closed after sending (python)

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, wireshark, tls1.2

I created a simple program to send strings from client on my PC to server on a different device.
I am using the code below for it.

```
host = '192.168.1.105'
portNumb = 5000

data="hello world"

soc=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

sslConn=context.wrap_socket(soc)

sslConn.connect((host,portNumb))

sslConn.send(data.encode())
```

When I checked in wireshark logs, the client is sending the string but closes the connection immediately, not even waiting for ACK from server. And the string is not reaching the server too (I checked the logs).

Could anyone suggest me a workaround? Is there something I'm missing like recv() or should I run server program along with this or anything?

Comment: *"When I checked in wireshark logs, the client is sending the string but closes the connection immediately, not even waiting for ACK from server."* - please show the actual output. The ACK is likely in the response to the FIN from the client. There might be a wrong expectation of how TCP/TLS works: The application does not wait for delivery - it sends the data to the OS kernel which then cares about delivery. If you want  the client to wait that the server has read and maybe processed the data you have to add some kind of application level acknowledgement in your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are  closing the connection, `sslConn.close`

```
sslConn.send(data.encode())

    while sslConn.recv(server_port_number) != "ack":

        print "waiting for ack"

    print "ack received!"

#send disconnect message    
                                                                                                                       
dmsg = "disconnect"

sslConn.send(dmsg)

sslConn.close()
```